# load a web page and click a button using c#

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a requirement to automate a procedure on a web page.

1. Open a web page
2. Find an input
3. Click on it
4. Close the web page

I would like to achieve all of the above using `c#` in a `console application`. I dont want to open any browser, but just a code to automate this process.

I have a `URL` to a web page and also `ID` of an input element.

What c# code should I use to achieve this.?

Comment: not possible in console , may be possible in windows forms/wpf with using some browser components

Comment: @Midhun It is possible in the console.. You can simulate the HTTP request using for example, `HttpClient` or in the case that the page is very JS-orientated, it is possible to emulate a browser engine inside a Console Application.

Comment: @Petrichor is it ??  you may fetch a web page contents . But how will you click a button ?

Comment: love you asad lots and lots

Answer (score 1):

I think this probably would be able to serve the purpose.

**Selenium 1 (Selenium RC)**: The Selenium Server which ***launches and kills browsers, interprets and runs the Selenese commands passed from the test program***, and acts as an HTTP proxy, intercepting and verifying HTTP messages passed between the browser and the AUT.

Selenium Server receives Selenium commands from your test program, interprets them, and reports back to your program the results of running those tests.

The RC server bundles Selenium Core and automatically injects it into the browser. This occurs when your test program opens the browser (using a client library API function). Selenium-Core is a JavaScript program, actually a set of JavaScript functions which interprets and executes Selenese commands using the browser’s built-in JavaScript interpreter.

The Server receives the Selenese commands from your test program using simple HTTP GET/POST requests. This means you can use any programming language that can send HTTP requests to automate Selenium tests on the browser.

For More: You can visit [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp)

Comment: Is it not possible without Selenium, using c# or jQuery?

Comment: I think it is possible but Selenium might be more easier. Just try it. U wud love it. It works like a charm. Just need to find the ID of the element on the page and you can fire the events.

Comment: This looks a splendid :)