# load web page and click to download file from console application

Tags: c#, console-application, webclient

I need to use C# Console Application.

I have a web Page URL

Inside the web page there is a button that downloads file by click

In View Source of the web page ,the button looks like this:

```
<a class="A" href="/myfiles/myfile.csv" target="_blank">הורד קובץ</a>
```

I should get the csv file in code by the URL.

How can I do it?

my question is similiar to this one , but not the same [load a web page and click a button using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780449/load-a-web-page-and-click-a-button-using-c-sharp) I didnt find an answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WebClient class to download the HTML. Parse it manually to pick out the href. Use the WebClient class again to make a call to the href target. This should cause the file content to be downloaded as a response to your HTTP request.